# Help simplifying equation (sample variance is an unbiased estimator)

Tags: probability, statistics

I would like to know how you get from this 
[image]

to $\sigma^2$.

I tried to simply as much as I could and got [image]

Comment: $n\sigma^2-\sigma^2=\sigma^2(n-1)$.

Comment: of course, why didn't I see that right away.